# Unique sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a unique sequence of positive numbers that starts with the number $1$ at the ﬁrst position and has the following properties.

- Each value in the sequence is greater than or equal to every value that appears earlier in the sequence.
- If the value at position $k$ in the sequence is $m$, then the number $k$ appears exactly $m$ times in the sequence.

The ﬁrst few numbers in this sequence are

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
\text{Position:}&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&\ldots\\
\text{Sequence value:}&1&2&2&3&3&4&4&4&5&5&5&6&\ldots
\end{array}$$

Notice, for instance, that the value at position $4$ in the sequence is $3$, so $4$ itself appears $3$ times in the sequence. What are the values that appear at position $411,1000$, and $1245$?

Comment: U see bro..... the Q is asked in ZIO....... so i guess we cant question a Q....

Comment: See http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C8&sort=&language=english&go=Search . It seems there is no nice formula, but it is quite quick to compute the first values

Answer (score 2):

As **charMD** implicitly noted in the comments, this is the [Golomb sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_sequence), [OEIS A001462](http://oeis.org/A001462). Both links give the recurrence

$$a_{n+1}=1+a\big(n+1-a(a(n))\big)$$

and the asymptotic estimate

$$a_n\approx\varphi^{2-n}n^{\varphi-1}\;,$$

where $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$, but there is apparently no known closed form. The OEIS entry has a number of references for further information, including a [link](http://oeis.org/A001462/b001462.txt) to a table of the first $10,000$ terms of the sequence.